# Perform add-type of an assembly that is signed with a strong name key

Tags: .net, powershell, .net-assembly

In PowerShell, is it possible to load an assembly that has been signed with a strong named key (.snk)?

I've tried the following:

```
Add-Type -Path <name of assembly>
$obj = New-Object -TypeName <namespace> 
$obj.<method>('hello')
```

And the result is:

Exception calling "" with "1" argument(s): "Not a valid calling assembly. The calling assembly is not signed."

Because of the type of environment I am working in, disabling the usage of the strong named key is not an option.

Is there a way to get PowerShell to load the .snk file to allow the usage of the assembly?

Comment: PowerShell have no problem in using strong name signed assemblies. In fact all build-in .NET framework assemblies as well as PowerShell own assemblies are strong name signed. My guess: given assembly do validation of calling assembly by its own.

Comment: There must be a way to specify a strong name key file to allow an assembly to be utilized. For a normal Visual Studio Solution you would modify the solutions settings and specify the strong name key file in the 'signing' tab to define the .snk file (a strong named key is generated with the 'sn /k key.snk'). What is the equivalent setting in PowerShell?